# Predict hierarchical outcome data

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to predict an outcome that is hierarchical. Specifically, industry classification codes found here: https://www.naics.com/search/

These are six digit numbers where the first two indicate a broad industry such as "Finance and Insurance". Nested within that category are anywhere from 10 to 50 more specific categories. However, knowing the top-level category eliminates many possibilities for the subsequent categories.

What modeling framework can handle this type of highly-dependent structure? My end goal is to predict the most specific category possible.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "the most specific category possible"? One way could be to run several classifiers on different levels of granularity.

The outcome of many classifiers, like logistic regression, is actually a number between 0 and 1 which can be interpreted as a degree of certainty with which a data point belongs to a class (according to the regression). Having classifications of several degrees of granularity for each point, you could choose the one with the highest certainty (or highest outcome from logistic regression/whatever classifier).